# Should I re-utilize my EF query method and if yes, how to do it

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I am using EF to get data from my MySQL database.

Now, I have two tables, the first is customers and project_codes.

The table project_codes have a FK to customers named id_customers. This way I am able to query which projects belong to a customer.

On my DAL, I got the following:

```
public List<customer> SelectAll()
{
    using (ubmmsEntities db = new ubmmsEntities())
    {
        var result = db.customers
                     .Include(p => p.project_codes)
                     .OrderBy(c=>c.customer_name)
                     .ToList();
        return result;

    }
}
```

That outputs to me all my customer and their respective project_codes.

Recently I needed to only get the project codes, so I created a DAL to get all the project codes from my database. But then I got myself thinking: "Should I have done that? Wouldn't be best to use my `SelectAll()` method and from it use Linq to fetch me the list of project_codes off all customers?

So this that was my first question. I mean, re-utilizing methods as much as possible is a good thing from a maintainability perspective, right?

The second question would be, how to get all the project_codes to a List? Doing it directly is easy, but I failed to achieve that using the `SelectAll()` as a base.

It worked alright if I had the customer_id using:

```
    ddlProject.DataSource = CustomerList.Where(x => x.id.Equals(customer_id))
.Select(p => p.project_codes).FirstOrDefault();
```

That outputed me the project codes of that customer, but I tried different approaches (foreach, where within whhere and some others at random) but they either the syntax fail or don't output me a list with all the project_codes. So that is another reason for me going with a specific method to get me the project codes.

Even if "common sense" or best practices says it is a bad idea to re-utilize the method as mentioned above, I would like some directions on how to achieve a list of project_codes using the return of `SelectAll()`... never know when it can come in hand.

Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a trade-off here; you are either iterating a larger collection (and doing selects, etc) on an *in-memory* collection, or iterating a smaller collection but having to go to a database to do it.

You will need to profile your setup to determine which is faster, but its entirely possible that the in-memory approach will be better (though stale if your data could have changed!).

To get all the project_codes, you should just need:

```
List<customer> customers; //Fill from DAL
List<project_code> allProjects = customers.SelectMany(c => c.project_codes).ToList();
```

Note that I used `SelectMany` to flatten the hierarchy of collections, I don't think `SelectAll` is actually a LINQ method.

Comment: It is a small collection, and this one is on a fast server. There is another one that is also small (2k lines) but the server is overloaded and it takes like 4~5 secs to return.Good point about the data changing, didn't consider that. For the use I am planning it should not be a problem. As for how select the projects, I am annoyed... I am certain that I tried `List<project_codes> projects = UBMMSController.GetAllCustomersEagerLoad().SelectMany(c => c.project_codes).ToList();` which is the same you did and it did not worked... now it did... likely i missed something back then. Thanks.

Comment: @EstevaoSantiago Glad to help :)